# Unpected token list error in trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am getting an error, unexpected token list in the following class;

```
trigger NotifyOppyOwnersOnCaseTrigger on Case (after update) {
//Specify template name
String EMAILTEMPLATE ='NotifyRepToCloseOpportunity';

NotifyOppyOwnerOnCaseTriggerHandler handler = new NotifyOppyOwnerOnCaseTriggerHandler();
        if ( Trigger.isUpdate ){
        String<List> toAddress = handler.findClosedCases(Trigger.New);
        handler.sendNotification(toAddress, EMAILTEMPLATE);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `List<String>` instead of `String<List>`